# 2checkout-nodejs Error Parsing JSON from 2Checkout API

Tags: node.js, error-handling, backend, payment-gateway, 2checkout

I was trying to implement 2checkout-nodejs as a payment method for an e-commerce website
but I kept on getting this error:

```
Error: Error parsing JSON response from 2Checkout API.
```

```
`const tco = new Twocheckout({   
apiUser: "my-username",   
apiPass: "my-password",   
sellerId: "my-seller-id",   
secretKey: "my-secret-word",   
privateKey: "my-private-key",   
secretWord: "secret-word",   
demo: false,   
sandbox: true, 
})`;
```

using this method:

`const params = {    privateKey: "my-private-key",    mode: "2CO",    li_0_name: "data",    li_0_price: "price",    first_name: "client-name",    last_name: "client-lastname",    email: "client-email",    address1: "client-address",    address2: "",    phone: "client-phone",    country: "country",    city: "city",    state: "state",    zip: "zip",    qty: "quantity",    currency_code: "currency code",  };`

I tried to log every step and everything but I kept getting the same error all the time and everything seems right except the outcome.

`await tco.checkout.authorize(JSON.stringify(params), (error, data) => {     if (error) {       console.log({ error });       res.status(301).json({ param: error, data: data });       // console.log(error);     } else { do something }`

Answer (score 0):

I dont know that is going to solve your problem but use double cot ("") for your keys too :

```
`const tco = new Twocheckout({   
"apiUser": "my-username",   
...
})`;
```

Comment: I already tried it. Nothing changed I received the same error again